# Firefox rendering

Tags: image, firefox

I've created an image of a very thin line and it looks fine in all the browsers except firefox. 
I've been trying to export it and to use in a lot of formats, raster ones, vector ones- nothing.
Are there any ways to make this line work for firefox correctly?
Images attached.
[Line in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2iyp.png)
[Line how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwAr2.png)

The problem solved. 
I guess it was because of the SVG format export properties.
Affinity Designer exports files in SVG format with a little different resolution then in editing was. If anybody's working with it-  Keep in mind.

Comment: Could you be more specific. Like what image format? Are you saving as a PNG-24 or PNG-32?  Does the image have transparency? More info please or better yet a jsfiddle or codepen example so we can test

Comment: PNG-24 with transparency, SVG image with rasterizing of this line, SVG image with vector line. Transparency on.

Comment: So you are using a SVG image element to pull in the PNG-24 image?

Comment: I've edited my question. Thank you